# Bug in Yahoo service or in Pandas DataReader

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the code below to download stock quotes and have come to realize that the quotes returned by the DataReader are differente from the ones I can download from Yahoo via their web page.
But I can't figure out if the problem is teh Yahoo feed or the DataReader.
Does anyone have any experience with this kind of problem?

```
def downloadQuotes(start_date, end_date, symbols, provider=PROVIDER):
    import pandas.io.data as web

    quotes = web.DataReader(symbols, provider, start_date, end_date)

    if len(quotes.major_axis) == 0:
       # show error message
       raise SystemExit    

    # change symbols to panel items
    quotes = quotes.transpose(2, 1, 0)

    print quotes['VWESX']['Adj Close'][0:23]
    ...
```

These are from the web page (only the last field matters):

```
1989-12-29,8.24,8.24,8.24,8.24,000,1.56
1989-12-28,8.25,8.25,8.25,8.25,000,1.55
1989-12-27,8.24,8.24,8.24,8.24,000,1.55
1989-12-26,8.25,8.25,8.25,8.25,000,1.55
1989-12-22,8.29,8.29,8.29,8.29,000,1.56
1989-12-21,8.31,8.31,8.31,8.31,000,1.56
1989-12-20,8.31,8.31,8.31,8.31,000,1.56
1989-12-19,8.31,8.31,8.31,8.31,000,1.56
1989-12-18,8.31,8.31,8.31,8.31,000,1.56
1989-12-15,8.30,8.30,8.30,8.30,000,1.56
1989-12-14,8.30,8.30,8.30,8.30,000,1.56
1989-12-13,8.30,8.30,8.30,8.30,000,1.56
1989-12-12,8.30,8.30,8.30,8.30,000,1.56
1989-12-11,8.30,8.30,8.30,8.30,000,1.56
1989-12-08,8.29,8.29,8.29,8.29,000,1.56
1989-12-07,8.29,8.29,8.29,8.29,000,1.56
1989-12-06,8.30,8.30,8.30,8.30,000,1.56
1989-12-05,8.31,8.31,8.31,8.31,000,1.56
1989-12-04,8.31,8.31,8.31,8.31,000,1.56
1989-12-01,8.30,8.30,8.30,8.30,000,1.56
```

and these from the above code:

```
1989-12-01    1.55
1989-12-04    1.56
1989-12-05    1.56
1989-12-06    1.55
1989-12-07    1.55
1989-12-08    1.55
1989-12-11    1.55
1989-12-12    1.55
1989-12-13    1.55
1989-12-14    1.55
1989-12-15    1.55
1989-12-18    1.56
1989-12-19    1.56
1989-12-20    1.56
1989-12-21    1.56
1989-12-22    1.55
1989-12-26    1.55
1989-12-27    1.54
1989-12-28    1.55
1989-12-29    1.55
```

Thanks,

JM